# Join outside Vertices

Tags: mesh, vertices

From an imported DXF file, line weights were taken over as faces. Now I have to connect the outer edges. Is there a simple way to do this?
[image]

Comment: That'll be a hassle to fix. Might as well go back to your DXF file, fix it in a CAD application and import again.

Comment: I found a complicated solution. Select both head edges, then "Edge Tools" "Angle off Edge", this extends the edges. Then i use "Tiny CAD" "VTX AUTO" to create a Corner Vertice.

Comment: TinyCAD would be my second choice too, but is really going to be a lot of work if you have many cases

Comment: Finally i did what you suggested and Re-Convert the dxf File. But this problem still needs a solution (maybe a Python script ?)